# Ruby - best approach to create a postgresql DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I am new to ruby. What is the best approach to make a simple postgresql DB via a ruby script? Can I use active record for this (not sure if it can be used via a ruby script)? or there are better alternatives?

I appreciate if you could help me with a ruby code snippet, or redirect me through a link.

Thanks.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, are you want to create new rails app and database app will use is postgres?

Comment: @Kien Thanh: No, I just wanna make a simple ruby script to be connected to a postgresql database.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with AlexFranco that you can easily achieve that with the `pg gem`.
However, when you read how to use the pg gem you might wonder which database you should connect to.. after all you want don't have a database yet, if you had you wouldn't want to create one..

Turns out there is a master-db called `postgres`. So here's a minimal working example:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PG.connect(dbname: 'postgres')
conn.exec("CREATE DATABASE foo")
```

See the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createdatabase.html) on options for the create database statement. More info on how to use the pg gem can be found in [the docs](http://deveiate.org/code/pg/).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can try with the pg gem,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'pg'

# Output a table of current connections to the DB
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'sales' )
conn.exec( "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity" ) do |result|
  puts "     PID | User             | Query"
  result.each do |row|
    puts " %7d | %-16s | %s " %
      row.values_at('procpid', 'usename', 'current_query')
  end
end
```

Here is the link where you can find information,and this example https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home